# Не удаётся поставить в автозагрузку script spawn-fcgi is not an executable regular file, skipped!

Tags: nginx, debian

дистрибутив: debian7установил nginx, php5-cli, php5-cgi и т.д.

### пишу

- /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p   9000 -u www-data -g www-data -f   /usr/bin/php5-cgi -P   /var/run/fastcgi-php.pid
- ps aux | grep php
- netstat -nlp | grep :9000

беру файл spawn-fcgi и кладу его в /etc/init.d

- далее #chmod 755   /etc/init.d/spawn-fcgi
- chkconfig spawn-fcgi on

и терминал сообщает мне: **script spawn-fcgi is not an executable regular file, skipped!**

**вот листинг части файловой системы  - меня смущают папки rc*:
 - http://s005.radikal.ru/i210/1312/85/af9ff789a790.png**

**вот скрин консоль - http://s019.radikal.ru/i624/1312/41/cff1157c22f9.png**

**а вот код  сам скрипт: - http://vk.com/doc220916068_255544747**

Буду очень рад помощи или просто совету, копался - не удалось изменить ситуацию

Comment: почитайте про формат файлов в init.d, т.к. у вас rdehat/centos подобный дистр читайте про него, это должен быть shell скрипт со спец комментариями и он должен принимать параметры start/stop для примера возьмите какой-нибудь скрипт из этой директории (поменьше) и переделайте под себя.

Comment: есть файл /etc/skeleton , шаблон инит скрипта ОС.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как ставшего абсолютно безсполезным, потому что наиболее существенная информация приведена (якобы) на картинке, которая уже удалена (на стороннем ресурсе).